# SNS Publish to multiple / group of endpoints

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is there a better way to send AWS SNS Push notifications to groups of users (i.e to users in a certain location) than this?

1. Create SNS Topic
2. Subscribe endpoints to topic
3. Publish to topic
4. Unsubscribe endpoints from topic
5. Delete topic

I am worried in cases where tens of thousands of users are in an area that AWS will limit my Subscribe calls or subscribing users will take a very long time.

Comment: SNS offers 10 million subscriptions per topic, and 100,000 topics per account.

Comment: ofcourse there are other solutions but it depends on how much effort you want spend developing such an component.